# Laravel use DB::table instead of ::find() to save or modify records

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my project I need to find some data from sql without using `id` in table. For example we can use this code to find data by `id`:

```
$result = BuyCard::find(10);
```

but I want to search in other table column such as `user_code` without changing laravel stucture instead if `id` with other column. I've tried this:

```
    $data = DB::table('buy_card_transactions')->where('transaction_id', $key)->first();
    $data->result_transaction = 1;
    $data->save();
```

For this code I'm getting an error but I can use it. But this code works fine:

```
    $data = DB::table('buy_card_transactions')->where('transaction_id', $key)->first();
    $data = BuyCard::find($data->id);
    $data->result_transaction = 1;
    $data->save();
```

how to edit this without using

```
$data = BuyCard::find($data->id);
```

between code? code is working fine but this is not correct.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

> Try to change this:

```
$data = DB::table('buy_card_transactions')->where('transaction_id', $key)->first();
```

> To:

```
$data = DB::table('buy_card_transactions')->where(array('transaction_id' => $key))->first();
```

> Or:

```
BuyCard::where('transaction_id',$key)->first();
```

Comment: Why use `where(array('transaction_id' => $key))` instead of  `where('transaction_id', $key)` ?

Comment: We use this when you are querying more than one identifier.

Comment: But in OP's case, he is querying on only one column. So how is array() going to help him?